# RSpec: FactoryBot is seeing duplicate definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm still new to using FactoryBot so I might be missing something. I am getting this error message:
[image]

Could it be due to improper set up in the spec_helper.rb file?

As for defining the user.rb factory, I tried including "associations: contracts" in the user.rb file. I'm still not sure if I should be doing that or is this current format fine for Rspec to pick up the association with contracts.rb?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'factory_bot_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  FactoryBot.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
  FactoryBot.find_definitions
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
```

spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    full_name "Test tester"
    email "test@tester.com"
    password "123456"
  end
end
```

spec/factories/contracts.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :contract do
    vendor "O2"
    starts_on "2019-03-08"
    ends_on "2019-03-10"
    price 30
  end
end
```

spec/requests/contracts_api_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "ContractsApi", type: :request do

  describe "POST #create" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      @current_user = AuthenticateUserCommand.call(@user.email, @user.password)
      @contract = @current_user.contracts.create(vendor: "Lebara", starts_on: "2018-12-12", ends_on: "2018-12-14", price: "15")
    end


    it 'creates a new contract' do
      expect { post api_v1_contracts_path, params: @contract }.to change(Contract, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need to configure FactoryBot in your **spec_helper.rb** and what you are doing there maybe be causing FactoryBot to load the factories twice.

Try changing the content of **spec_helper.rb** to just:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
```

Also, considering that you are including `FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods`, in your tests you can simply use `@user = create(:user)` instead of `@user = FactoryBot.create(:user)`

Comment: I did as you suggested, and now I'm getting the error message: ArgumentError: Factory not registered: contracts? Do you think the association is not being picked up?

Comment: I second the opinion that you're somehow requiring the files twice. YOu could try debugging it by putting `puts 'here I load factory X'` in first line of one of factory files and see if it shows up twice. Then you could try to get backtraces and see where it's loaded from.

Comment: Hey @MLZ do you have any other code that is using `FactoryBot.create(:contracts)` ? The error message suggests that you are trying to create `FactoryBot.create(:contracts)` instead of `FactoryBot.create(:contract)` (singular)

Comment: Mike and Rafael, thanks for weighing in. I've decided to use a PORO for now for simplicity, but might come back to this issue later on.